# How to set text in binder TextView from Fragment/Activity?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have two-way binded TextView by DataBinding in my XML and I want to set there text from Fragment and then get this to the ViewModel. This is possible?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_text_view"
        android:text="@={hourlyViewModel.location}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

EDIT:

The problem is resolved. I didn't set viewmodel in my fragment.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way Did you read this documentation? It should be enough to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can `setText` in your XML with data which gets from item model;

```
<data>
<variable
     name="item"
     type="com.xxx.xxx" />
</data>
```

`android:text="@{item.xxx}"`